# Label 'setString' method turns it upside down?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I have the following line of code in the `update` method of HelloWorldScene.cpp of the Xcode (v6.4) project generated from Cocos2d (v2.3.2), compiling for iPhone 4S

```
scoreLabel->setString(StringUtils::format("%d", GameManager::sharedGameManager()->GetScore()));
```

scoreLabel is a standard Label, and GetScore returns an integer score.
When this line of code is commented out, it displays the default Text value for the Label.
When the line of code is present, it displays the default Text value upside down (I set the default value to 7)

Why??

Comment: Could you please show some more code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set  any default value in your init method